# Code Coverage under PHPUnit for admin areas

Tags: php, http-headers, phpunit, code-coverage

I'm trying to get PHPUnit and CodeCoverage over a few hundred PHP code repositories. A consistent problem I receive is that CodeCoverage doesn't work over any of my Admin pages that have session_start or any of my bounce-redirect pages that use header('Location...'); Code that otherwise works fine throws up "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ...)"

I've tried any number of Google searches to find a way around this and my Google-fu is currently weak. Thanks in advance.

EDIT 20120515:
I've ensured my code has all exit() calls replaced with returns. I do have XDebug installed and it is functioning on very simple, non-authenticated applications.

EDIT 20120531:
Reading further into the code, I found a file_get_contents in the SeleniumTestCase.php was failing under my xampp due to the file_get_contents('https://...'). Solved it by creating a http:// virtual host on a different port and pointing my coverageScriptUrl at that instead. All the warnings above were apparently red herrings.

Comment: What are you running to collect coverage data?

Comment: <phpunit>
 <logging>
   <log type="coverage-html" target="logs/coverage"
        yui="false" highlight="false"/>
   <log type="coverage-php" target="logs/coverage.serialized"/>
   <log type="coverage-clover" target="logs/coverage.xml"/>
   <log type="coverage-text" target="php://stdout" showUncoveredFiles="false"/>
   <log type="junit" target="logs/logfile.xml" logIncompleteSkipped="false"/>
   <log type="testdox-html" target="logs/testdox/index.html" />
   </logging>
</phpunit>

Comment: Note I've trimmed out the whitelist and php area of the above so it fits in the comment.

Comment: You're allowed to edit your question and extend it with new facts... precisely so you didn't have to squeezing stunts.  However, my questions was really trying to get at whether (I assume) you have Xdebug running.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Yes, XDebug is running (otherwise it tells me that code coverage will not execute). If I run for very simple cases without redirects or logins that require sessions, code coverage works fine. It's only if any PHP page contains a session_start() or header() call the code coverage fails.

Comment: Hmm.  I don't really know the answer to your problem.  But it may have something to do with how PHP treats HTML-producing pages.  When such pages are loaded, PHP implicitly outputs HTML header information, and expects your page to "continue" with sensible HTML data.  If you don't do that, get the kind of complaint you are seeing.  Now, you have working pages already, based on their top-to-bottom execution under normal circumstances.  When you run a unit test, the page gets loaded (you get the header output), and then you run a unit test rather than the "next thing on the page" ...

Comment: ... which is likely one of the header() or session() calls (look at the top of an offending page); I suspect the unit you are testing when you get the problem is outputting HTML.   You may need to modify your unit test to invoke the top-of-page actions, and you may need to modify those top-of-pages actions to remember they have been, so they run only once.   Hope this helps.